# cufon font-size is not changing smoothly on hover event in order to produce fisheye effect on menu(text)

Tags: jquery, cufon

this is my first post about Cufon font as i am new to jquery & javascript. I am trying to create vertical fisheye effect on menu i.e on text. what i want is when i hover over a current menu,font-size of current menu as well as font-size of 2 sub-menu both above and below should change smoothly.It was working correctly before using Cufon font, but right now there is a delay at about 1/2 sec which affects the smoothness of effect.

Here is my html file.....................

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-yui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/my-custom-font_400.font.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     Cufon.replace('#scroller ul li a', { 
     fontFamily: 'my-custom-font',
     hover:true
   });
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
     <div id="rollerBox">
           <div id="scroller" >    
                    <ul id="innerContainer">
                        <li class="pictures1"><a href="#">link1</a></li>
                        <li class="pictures2"><a href="#">link2</a></li>
                        <li class="pictures3"><a href="#">link3</a></li>
                        <li class="pictures4"><a href="#">link4</a></li>
                        <li class="pictures3"><a href="#">link5</a></li>
                        <li class="pictures4"><a href="#">link6</a></li>
                  </ul> <!-- #keywords -->                      
           </div> <!-- #scroller -->                     
      </div> <!-- #rollerBox --
    </body>
   </html>
```

and here is my code for fisheye  effect(on text-menu).........

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#scroller ul li a").hover(function(){
         $(this).css({"font-size":"28px","color":"green"})
         $(this).parent().next().children().css({"font-size":"26px"})
         $(this).parent().prev().children().css({"font-size":"26px"})
         $(this).parent().nextAll().eq(1).children().css({"font-size":"25px"})
         $(this).parent().prevAll().eq(1).children().css({"font-size":"25px"})
        Cufon.refresh();
   },function(){   
         $(this).css({"font-size":"24px","color":"white"})
         $(this).parent().next().children().css({"font-size":"24px"})
         $(this).parent().prev().children().css({"font-size":"24px"})
         $(this).parent().nextAll().eq(1).children().css({"font-size":"24px"})
         $(this).parent().prevAll().eq(1).children().css({"font-size":"24px"})
       Cufon.refresh();
   })
  })
```